# When creats fsc an init@ variable?

Tags: f#, fsc

If I deserialize from XML I get the following error:`The initialization of an object or value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized.`

My F# code looks as following:

```
[<...>]
[<...>]
[<DataContract>]
type DerivedClass() as X = class
    inherit BaseClass()
    [<DataMember>]
    [<Input>]
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable MemberName: myType  
    ....
```

I used ILSpy to look at the result and getting the init@117 value that guards against Access before initilazation.

```
...       
[..., DataContract]
[System.Serializable]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
[..., DefaultValue, DataMember]
public modulName.myType  MemberName;

internal int init@117;
    ...
```

All my other classes don't get an init@ variable and deserialize as expected. Why is the init@ sometimes created and sometimes not? The answer could help me to fix my code.

**Edit**

The number after the @ stands for the sourc code line of the type.

**Edit 2**

Referencing the type with `as` creates the  `HasSelfReferentialConstructor` reponsible for the `InstanceMembersNeedSafeInitCheck` so changing

```
...
type DerivedClass() as X = class
...
```

to

```
...
type DerivedClass()  = class
...
```

solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing the type with `as` creates the  HasSelfReferentialConstructor`reponsible for theInstanceMembersNeedSafeInitCheck` so changing

```
...
type DerivedClass() as X = class
...
```

to

```
...
type DerivedClass()  = class
...
```

solved the issue for me.

Comment: This detail actually caused a significant performance regression for me once.

Comment: The ``do`` looks nice in the type Definition but a ``new()`` produce the more performant code. Took me some time to figure out, finaly looked in the compiler to find the reason for creating the ``init@``